# Laravel 4: how to remember a user when logging him in using Auth::login

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

My users can login using social options (Facebook, Twitter) and so I don't use the `Auth::attempt()` method, but the `Auth::login()`.

How can I remember my users so the don't have to login every time they restart the browser?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not in the docs, but if you look at the code;

```
public function login(UserInterface $user, $remember = false)
```

So just do

```
Auth::login($user, true);
```

Comment: That's it. I did search the code, though, but only came to AuthManager.php, etc.

Comment: Source code for reference: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Auth/Guard.php#L190